# How to match a particular URL pattern in Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am having trouble matching a pattern of this format: `p#.g.com` where # is not a 1 or a 2. For instance if the pattern is `p1.g.com`, I don't need to match. If it it `p2.g.com`, I don't need to match.

But if it is any other number, such as `p3.g.com` or `p29.g.com`, then I need to match.

My current pattern is `r"(?P<url>p([^1,2])\.g\.com)"`, but this fails if the pattern is p##.g.com, basically any two digit number it fails on. There is no upper limit on the #, so it could be a 3 or 999 or anything in between.

I also tried `r"(?P<url>p([^1,2])\d+\.g\.com)"` but that does not match any number beginning with a 1 or a 2. For instance 11 or 23 are not matched, which I do want matched.

Comment: try, ``p\d+\.g\.com`` ?

Comment: That's going to match p1.g.com and p2.g.com, which I don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
p(?:[03-9]|\d{2,})\.g\.com
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RYH5Sc/2)

##### Explanation:

- Matches character `p`
- Start of non-capturing group

  - Match one of:

    - The digits 0 or 3-9
    - Any double digit number like 10 or higher
- Matches character  `.g.com`